# How can i show user's current country when user denies location access in Google map?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, core-location

Is there any way to show the user's current country instead user location when user denies location access of the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract location from ip address. You'll get the country and region easily from ip address but you can't get the exact location.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it from the `Locale`:

```
let code = Locale.current.identifier
let reg = Locale.current.regionCode
let desc = Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: Locale.current.identifier)
```

produces:

```
"en_US"
"US"
"English (United States)"
```